# Join two values of a hash to form a hash in ruby

Tags: ruby, hashtable

I have a hash with keys, "parameter_name" and "parameter_value", and want to produce a hash with one key-value pair, the value of "parameter_name" being the key and the value of "parameter_value" being the value.
The hash looks something like this:

```
p = {"parameter_name"=>"NumberOfRetries", "parameter_value"=>"3"}
```

The way I want the output to be is like,

```
{"NumberOfRetries"=>"3"}
```

I have tried:

```
a = p.values.map {|v| v1,v2=v[0],v[1]; {v1=>v2} }
```

but doing that doesn't return the right output and it produces the following,

```
[{"N"=>"u"}, {"3"=>nil}]
```

Can somebody help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: What do the other elements look like ?

Comment: [{"N"=>"u"}, {"3"=>nil}]

Comment: Is there a pattern? How do you know which 2 key/values to combine into a new one

Comment: `{ p['parameter_name'] => p['parameter_value'] }` ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: BTW, your "array of Hash elements" is simply a hash.

Comment: Your desired result implies that `p` has two keys. If you know what those keys are, @Stefan's suggestion is best because it makes clear to the reader exactly what you are doing.

Comment: It is common for SO questions, like this one, to frame the question in terms of an example. Don't do that! Examples are meant to help clarify the question, but *never* provide an unambiguous statement of the question. Here you might write something like the following (assuming my interpretation is correct), "I am given a hash with keys, `"parameter_name"` and `"parameter_value"`, and want to produce a hash with one key-value pair, the value of `"parameter_name"` being the key and the value of `"parameter_value"` being the value. For example, if `p = {...}` my desired result would be `{...}"...

Comment: ...However, my understanding of the question may not be correct. The keys may not be known. In that case you need to refer to the *order* of the hash's keys (which will be in order of insertion). That is not likely to be good programming practice, however. Note also that you said: 1) I am given `p`; 2) I tried X, 3) X doesn't work, 4) I want Y. You should be saying:  I am given `p`, 2) I want Y, 3) I tried X, 4) X results in Z which is incorrect (or X raises the exception "...."). Your statement is akin to, "I have a car. I changed the head gasket. That didn't work. I want to change the oil."

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks for the suggestions. Will them in mind while posting questions next time. I have edited the post as per your suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a hash with keys, "parameter_name" and "parameter_value", and want to produce a hash with one key-value pair, the value of "parameter_name" being the key and the value of "parameter_value" being the value.

To get the value of `"parameter_name"` you'd use: (given your example hash `p`)

```
p["parameter_name"] #=> "NumberOfRetries"
```

for the value of `"parameter_value"`:

```
p["parameter_value"] #=> "3"
```

A hash with a single *key* / *value* pair is created via: (assigned to `a`)

```
a = { key => value }
```

Using the value of `"paramter_name"` as *key* and the value of `"parameter_value"` as *value* gives:

```
a = { p["parameter_name"] => p["parameter_value"] }
#=> { "NumberOfRetries" => "3" }
```

Referring to the hash values by their keys ensures that this works regardless of the hash order, or if unrelated key / value pairs are present, e.g.:

```
p = { "parameter_value"=>"3", "foo"=>"bar", "parameter_name"=>"NumberOfRetries" }

a = { p["parameter_name"] => p["parameter_value"] }
#=> { "NumberOfRetries" => "3" }
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this.

```
a = Hash[*p.map(&:last)]
```

Comment: Wow! That worked. Can you explain to me how it works?

Comment: @GulduKumar Break it down step-my-step; it'll be a good learning experience.

Comment: `p.map(&:last)` makes array with values.  `Hash[*]` makes hash from arrays.

Comment: `Hash[*p.values]` or `[p.values].to_h`.

Comment: With the clarification of question this no longer works, as it assumes the hash's keys are in a particular order.